# using python to parse xml data

Tags: python, xml

I have a question with regards to XML and python. I want to comb through this xml file and look for certain tags, and then within those tags look for where there is data separated by a comma. split that and make a new line. I have the logic down, im just not too familiar with python to know whoch modules I should be researching. Any help as to where i should start researching would help.

172.28.18.142,10.0.0.2

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think when it comes to xml parsing in python there are a few options: `lxml`, `xml`, and `BeautifulSoup`. Most of my experience has dealt with the first two and I've found `lxml` to be extraordinarily faster than `xml`. Here's an `lxml` code snippet for parsing all elements of the root with a particular tag and storing the comma-separated text of each tag as a list. I think you'll want to add a lot of `try` and `except` blocks and tinker with the details, but this should get you started.

```py
from lxml import etree

file_path = r'C:\Desktop\some_file.xml'
tree = etree.parse(file_path)
info_list = []
my_tag_path = tree.xpath('//topTag')
for elem in my_tag_path:
    if elem.find('.//childTag') is not None:
        info_list.append(elem.xpath('.//childTag')[0].text.split(','))
```

Comment: A dictionary with increasing, consecutive integer numbers starting at 0 as keys should be a list and not a dictionary.

Comment: Fair enough, I took the example from a script that builds a Pandas Dataframe object from the parsed data and didn't think twice about it. I'll update the answer.